# Set Powershell as the default shell of Far Manager?

Tags: powershell, far-manager

Can I set Powershell as the default shell of Far Manager?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With PowerShellFar in Far Manager you can invoke PowerShell commands right from
the command line with the prefix `ps:`. That is:

```
Commands with console output, prefix ps:

    ps: Get-Date
    ps: 3.14 / 3
    ps: [math]::pi / 3

Commands with viewer output, prefix vps:

    vps: Get-Process
    vps: Get-ChildItem C:\TEMP\LargeFolder -Recurse -Force

Commands starting UI or background jobs normally use prefix ps:

    ps: $Far.Msg("Hello world!")
    ps: Get-Process | Out-FarList -Text Name | Open-FarPanel
    ps: Start-FarJob { Remove-Item C:\TEMP\LargeFolder -Recurse -Force }
```

If you expect lengthy output consider to start Far Manager as `Far.exe /w`.

Finally see built-in PowerShellFar help, sections `Command line` and `FAQ`. You
can define some accelerators. For example I use `[Space]` which inserts `ps:`
into the empty command line. Thus, actually I have to type just 1 more symbol.
This is a little bit inconvenient but it is perfectly compensated by the
standard CMD shell at hands, CMD is not dead, especially in Far Manager.

Comment: hi @RomanKuzmin, i try to set the accelerators as is explained in the help but when i write ">: Set-FarMacro Shell Space '> : Space' 'Easy prefix' -CommandLine 0" it trows that Set-FarMacro isn't found. When i execute >: gcm *far* i see all the far cmdlet but Set-FarMacro is missing. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should at first invoke `Import-Module FarMacro` (or F11 \ PSF \ Modules \ FarMacro). I should have mentioned this in help (will do, thanks).

Comment: Thanks Roman that was the missing step, :). I have only two more thing that bothers me about Farmanager but i'm going to search where to ask that, maybe you could give some light...(after working with it, if i return to the console the actual character mark dissapear and the insert mode is on (overwrite mode), and  what is more incredible is that if i press insert to deactivate the insert mode, after entering a line, the insert mode appears again)

Answer (score 6):

[PowerShellFar](https://github.com/nightroman/FarNet/wiki/PowerShellFar) allows you to integrate PowerShell into Far Manager.

> PowerShellFar combines the rich console based
>   user interface of Far Manager with
>   full power of Windows PowerShell
>   perfectly integrated into this
>   original text friendly environment.

[image]

Comment: yea i know but how the default shell could work with powershell. That extensions allows me to execute powershell commands trough the menu f11..powershellfar..invoke.... i want to execute posh without doing all of that, if you look in the bottom of powershell far there is a command line, but for default works with cmd, :( i wanna change that

Comment: Its simply not possible.

Answer (score 6):

An option that has not been mentioned so far (and it is not so great because out of the box, there is no auto completion), but you can enter

```
far:config
```

and scroll down until you find this setting:

```
System.Executor.Comspec                   │string │%COMSPEC%
System.Executor.ComspecArguments          │string │/S /C "{0}"
```

You can change it like so:

```
System.Executor.Comspec                   │string │powershell
System.Executor.ComspecArguments          │string │-c "{0}"
```

This will allow you to run PowerShell commands directly from the FAR shell.